# Scrolling a small image with its content

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

I am working on a web template where the green button need to be scrolled with text.
When I will scroll with my mouse the green button should come down.
When I will scroll up, it will go up.
Just like in the photo:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use `vanilla javascript`? or `jquery`?

Comment: anything will work.. just need a solution

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Comment: I haven't tried.. I just dont know from where I have to start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of create a custom scrollbar just style it in `css`, Try this:

```css
html, body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height:0px;
}
.container{
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
p{
  height:auto;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #ccc; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: green;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-radius:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
    background: #555; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. This the text. 
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the scrollbar an input element , because there is a "range" input type that acts as a scrollbar.

Hope that this helps you.